# Problem on Symfony Mailer with SMTP and certificate ssl not valid

Tags: symfony, ssl, openssl, symfony4, mailer

**Symfony version(s) affected: 4.4.3**

**Mailer component (not swiftmailer)**

**Description**
i try to send a mail on the SMTP server but this one don't have a certicate valid.
So How to disable the ssl ?

**How to reproduce**
the error :

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Comment: Can you show how you send email ?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it if you'r using swiftmailer

````
swiftmailer:
   stream_options:
    ssl:
        verify_peer: false
        verify_peer_name: false```
````

Comment: What do you use as DSN ?

Comment: smtp://127.0.0.1:25

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with the following code:

```
$transport = Transport::fromDsn('smtp://smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT?verify_peer=false');
```

in case of using gmail, you must create an app password.

I hope I helped you.